# React.js fails to dynamically apply CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, websocket

We're having issues with using react object className as a props variable. This is keeping us from dynamically loading an image by detecting the class name & matching the name to the correct image in a large CSS sprite (100+ images). The data is sent continually via a websocket endpoint, and as the react object changes, we need to display a new image.

During debugging we can see that className has been applied to the element, but the image isn't loading correctly and the class seems to be inactive.

```
var Item = React.createClass(
    {
        displayName: 'Item',
        render: function(){
            var itemClass = classNames("item", this.props.name);
            return (
                <div className={itemClass} ></div>
            )
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of `react`.

Check if your are adding proper `class` of the image. If yes, try inspecting the style `property` of the class. There is a possible chance that you have given a `invalid` `css` value for a `property`

Comment: When you say it can't be possible, do you mean it should not be giving an error? Or do you mean what we're doing is not possible?

Comment: The problem is not because of `react` or `classnames`. It might be because of the way you handle it or the `css`

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tip. Will take a look and post what we find in the morning.

Comment: Some say @codefame died on his quest to find the problem.